# I am getting a Compile time error ,Windows module is not valid type (VBA,Macros).(CATIA V5)

Tags: vba, scripting, catia

I am learning VBA with CATIA scripting(macros). My code looks like this

```
Sub CATMain()
  Dim oPart1 As Document
  Set oPart1 = CATIA.ActiveDocument
  Dim currentWindow As Windows 'I am getting an error here 
  Set currentWindow = CATIA.Windows
  Dim openWind As Integer
  openWind = currentWindow.Count
End Sub
```

I get this kind of errors with other collections too, some of them work whenever I make a new project library, but this one is not going away

I have tried to find an answer on many forums and even here we have some similar topics, but I didn't get an answer to my issue

Comment: Either `Dim currentWindow` or `Dim currentWindow As object` should do.

Comment: what ? you mean instaed of windows i should do object?

Comment: @PEH  that was just to highlight the error obviously i was not using that in my code

Comment: @Juliet.K Highlighting in code blocks doesn't work, therefore I removed it, also your code comment specifies the line of error. • Please note that the tag [tag:macros] must not be used for VBA languages (see tag info), therefore I removed it.

Comment: @Pᴇʜ Thanks for your generosity, This issue has been resolved now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you have another "Windows" object type in your references which is making the definition ambiguous.

Try this:

```
     Dim wx as INFITF.Windows
```

Personally I normally don't bother with defining variables for the collection properties. For example I would just use "CATIA.Windows" whenever I needed to reference the collection of windows.

Also, if you have multiple versions of CATIA installed, or have uninstalled a version lately, it is possible the the incorrect version of the libraries are registered. This will cause errors like you are seeing.

So if you have multiple versions (or have uninstalled recently) Run "CNext.exe -regserver" from the exe folder of the version you want to use.

Comment: @C R Johnson I tried your example .but it is not working, if I do the object then it works

Comment: Did you try CNEXT.exe -regserver?     If you go to Tools->References for your project, is CATIA V5 InfInterfaces selected? Is is referring to the correct version? (the references dialog will show the path). Finally, if you use the VBA Object browser, can you find the reference to INFITF.Windows?

Comment: Yes, it's working now, that library was not selected. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have any recommendation or any good  source for beginners with CATIA+VBA ?

Answer (score 1):

@Jeeped your suggestion solved my issue,
posting it here as an answer just to close this issue. Thanks!

```
Dim currentWindow As Object
Set currentWindow = CATIA.Windows
```